# Same ftp upload issue on any live distribution I tried

Tags: linux, ftp

I have just installed Linux Mint Petra 16 after trying more live distributions. The problem I am facing right now, is that I can't upload anything on any ftp server. The upload speed doesn't exceed 0.20kb, which is practically 0, it starts at about 20KB/s and than quickly drops to 0.3-0.5KB/s.

When downloading from any ftp server, everything is fine. I had this problem with any Linux distribution I tried (live instances). I tested my speed, and got about 30 Mbps for both uploading and downloading. I also have Windows 7 installed on my pc and I have no problems whatsoever there. I tried different ftp clients and the result is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms are consistent with your network causing packet fragmentation when packets are over a certain size. If this is the case, then running the following command (as root) should show a drastic improvement:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mtu_probing
```

The option is described in the `tcp(7)` man page.

Otherwise, I would run wireshark or tcpdump to capture the packets making up the connection, and I would look for delayed or missing ACKs, and try to spot a pattern.